# Solve using Z3 solver a condition with a length of an arbitrary size array

Tags: python, z3, solver, z3py

I'm learning Z3 solver. I have a question about Arrays and related conditions. In particular, I have to create Z3py code to solve the if condition below:

```
totalAccounts = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]    

def (myAccounts):
   cnt = len(myAccounts)
   if (cnt > 10) doSomething()
```

`myAccounts` is a list of Integers, subset of the list `totalAccounts`.
The condition to pass is `cnt > 10` which depends on the *length* of `myAccounts` list.

I think I need to represent `myAccounts` as a Z3's Array and copy the values in `totalAccounts` on it using the function `Store`.

```
MYACCOUNTS = Array ('MYACCOUNTS', IntSort(), IntSort())
I = Int('I')
i = 0
for elem in totalAccounts:
  MYACCOUNTS = Store(MYACCOUNTS, i, elem)
  i = i + 1
```

But I don't know how to represent the length of such array in creating the condition to add to the solver:

```
solver = Solver()
solver.add( ??? > 10 )
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMTLib arrays (and consequently z3 and z3py arrays) are indexed by their entire domain type. In your example, the index type is `Int()`, so the array has an element for any integer value. Note that this is different than the usual treatment of arrays in programming languages where you usually get a "length" of an array. You can read more about SMTLib arrays here: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf (page 39, in particular.)

To model any notion of array length, one typically keeps track of it in a separate symbolic variable, and whenever properties are expressed, it's typically done in reference to that variable. Asking exactly what problem you're trying to solve will get you further.

You might also want to review the Z3 guide (https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide), which also has a section on arrays. Stack-overflow also has similar questions regarding array usage in z3py, here's one example answer, relevant to the current context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743450/936310